# How to design reusable context menus?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm developing a WinForms .NET application. I have few context menus which are used on various places including some user controls. There is no ultimate root form which could hold those menus (I could design in those form's designer) on a single place.

I would like to make those menus standalone controls and be able to drop them from Toolbox wherever I need. I know how to do it programmatically/dynamically but without designer support. Perhaps I'm just missing something.

- Is there a way how to make those menus design-able?
- What is the best practice?

Comment: Go with programmatically-generated menus, I'm doing this, too.

Comment: If your context menus are static and after you add them to the designer you don't want to change items of them, you can have such components. Do you need such context menu strips?

Comment: I generally use the designer to make a dummy form with the context menu, and then I extract this code out into a helper function that all my forms can access. It's a two step process, but it works.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: Basically yes, that is what I need. I mean - I may add some items later when new features are added but during design time, not run time.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I see, I thought about that too but wondered whether there is a better way. And tell me - do you extract designer generated code to such a helper function (which complicates things when you need to add some more items later) or do your helper function instantiate that dummy form and grabs context menus from that (which will take some resources because form needs handle to be created)? The latter case is dirty but basically exactly fits my needs.

Comment: @mancze - I tend to copy and paste the designer code in one lump, if possible. Then just update as needed from the designer form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a reusable custom context menu which is available in toolbox. To do so, it's enough to create a public class in the project which inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip` and put the codes for creating items in constructor of your class.

Also you can do it using designer:

- Add a new class `CustomContextMenuStrip` to your project
- Make it public and inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip` and save it.
- Double click on file to open it in design mode which shows an empty area with a message which tells you can add some components.
- In property window, click `Items` property and add items that you need.
- It will creates the codes for items in `InitializeComponent()` method. Go to code view of the file and add a public parameterless constructor and call `InitializeComponent()` in it.
- If you build the project, your custom component will add to toolbox in your project Components tab at top of toolbox.

**Note:**

- Using the designer approach has benefits of using designer, for example using the designer, you can make your component localizable by setting `Language` property which is available only in designer. This way your component itself is localizable, independent from host form.
- You can follow this approach for all components and controls which are inheritable and it's not restricted to `ContextMenuStrip`.
- You can add behavior to menu items by adding event handlers in your custom class. Also if you need to let the forms that host your component add event handlers, you can hanlde `ItemClicked` in forms.
- Whilst you can see those items in designer of host forms, but you can not change them using designer of the host forms.

Comment: I'll be damned. This is exactly it. I missed that I can still customize such control via Properties window. I did not read designer message properly.