# How to define and store menustrips and context menus in a class library in a designer-editable way?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I have some plug-ins defined as class libraries in C# (Visual Studio 2010). Each of these plug-ins, after being loaded, should add its own menu items to the main menu of the main app, and some context-menus to other GUI components. As these plug-ins are implemented as class libraries, how could I design, define, and store those menus and context-menus? AFAIK, they cannot be part of the class library as designer-editable files.

Comment: Pass the strip/menu to the assembly and it can do whatever it likes with it?  or implement relevant AddItem methods to the interface that return the new items to add?

Comment: Thanks, But plug-in developers need to be able to define their menu and context menu in VS ***DESIGNERS***.

Comment: It seems this is what you are looking for: [How to design reusable context menus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294266/how-to-design-reusable-context-menus). Then at run-time you can simply use them or merge those reusable menus which created using designer in your dll with the host application.

Comment: Thank you Reza. I read your suggested link. It looks promising, but I still have a problem unsolved: Nothing editable is shown in Design View, only "Items Designer Editor" is available.
Also, there I see a good suggestion for a potential solution, by Mancze: "Make a dummy form, then grabbing context menus from that". Can this solution be implimented?

Comment: The suggestion (pointed in the above link) by Mancze has the advantage that menus are directly visible and editable, and looks visually more straight forward. Can that solution be implemented?